# CSS - How to insert an animatable offset border behind an image?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

I can't replicate the layout below using CSS where the black border is offset and behind the picture:

[image]

I tried using the `border` property, but that obviously didn't work as I don't know if it's possible to offset it.

Ideally, I should also be able to move/animate that border so that the offset is reduced when hovering the image.

Comment: My CSS is rubbish but I'd guess that's an unfilled [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simpler solution: Using box-shadow

If the background under your image has a single plain color, you can use `box-shadow` with 2 shadows:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
  
body {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.frame {
  height: 75vh;
  box-shadow:
    10px -10px 0 -5px yellow,
    10px -10px 0 0 black;
    
  transition: box-shadow ease-in 150ms;
}

.frame:hover {
  box-shadow:
    5px -5px 0 -5px yellow,
    5px -5px 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<img class="frame" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/7WjgW/s3/1974-lancia-stratos-hf-stradale-for-sale.jpg" />
```

#### Limitations when using box-shadow

If the background is not plain, you would not be able to properly mask the unwanted portion of your undermost shadow, so you will get something like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
  
body {
  background: linear-gradient(cyan, yellow);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.frame {
  height: 75vh;
  box-shadow:
    10px -10px 0 -5px cyan,
    10px -10px 0 0 black;
    
  transition: box-shadow ease-in 150ms;
}

.frame:hover {
  box-shadow:
    5px -5px 0 -5px cyan,
    5px -5px 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<img class="frame" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/7WjgW/s3/1974-lancia-stratos-hf-stradale-for-sale.jpg" />
```

#### Better but more complex solution: Using a wrapping element around the image with a pseudoelement with a border

The solution to the problem above would be to use a wrapping element around that image. That element would then have a pseudoelement (`::before`or `::after`) with a `border` instead of a `box-shadow`.

To animate/move it, you would then use `transform` instead of changing the border itself:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
  
body {
  background: linear-gradient(cyan, yellow);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  height: 75vh;
  display: block;
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
}

.frame::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid black;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transition: transform 150ms;
}

.frame:hover::before {
  transform: translate(5px, -5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img  src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/7WjgW/s3/1974-lancia-stratos-hf-stradale-for-sale.jpg" />
</div>
```

Note that I have also added `box-sizing: border-box`. Otherwise, the `::before` pseudoelement size would be the size of the parent + the width of the borders around it, so the border would look bigger than the image. When using `box-sizing: border-box` the size of the borders and paddings are subtracted from the total size instead.

#### Performance note

Have you noticed that the last example moves more smoothly and maybe faster than the other two? That's because [your browser is now using hardware acceleration to move it](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/), which was not the case before.

Therefore, if you need to move/animate that, I would advise you to use this method. Otherwise, if you have a plain background and the border is not animated, then you could use the `box-shadow` method, which involves just a few lines of CSS.

Comment: Hi @Insomnia, welcome to StackOverflow! Good to know this has helped you (: Remember you can always [accept the answer (only one) that you think better solved your problem, by clicking the checkbox on the left side of the answer, and vote as many answers as you want if you think they are helpful and well-researched](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way but I would solve it like this:

```css
.frame-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.frame-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code, it would be hard to tell where the issue is. But try putting your image in its own  and applying a border to the div itself.